# How do you extend a cascades ui control

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm trying to extend the webview control in cascades with the following code

```
#include <bb/cascades/WebView>

namespace mopub {

class BrowserView : public WebView {
```

my compile error is *expected class-name before '{' token*

I've tried to extend QWebView and #include  but to avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either specify using bb::cascades

```
using namespace bb::cascades;
```

Or fully qualify the super class

```
class BrowserView : public bb::cascades::WebView {
```